# Correct Date format for Developer Console Query Editor?

Tags: soql, developer-console, query-editor

I'm trying to debug a SOQL query in the developer console's query editor.  This works

```
SELECT Site__c, Cluster__c, Date__c, Num_Att_records__c FROM Session__c 
Where Session__c.SiteProgram__r.Name = 'Brattleboro'
```

I'm having trouble getting the date format right for the following:

```
SELECT Site__c, Cluster__c, Date__c, Num_Att_records__c FROM Session__c 
Where Session__c.SiteProgram__r.Name = 'Brattleboro' AND Date__c = 2012-11-6
```

With the date as shown, I get the message "Unknown error parsing query"

If I put the date in quotes, I don't see the the parsing error message, but I get the following message when I press the execute button

"[object Object]: 'Brattleboro' AND Date__c = '2012-11-6' ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:147 value of filter criterion for field 'Date__c' must be of type date and should not be enclosed in quotes"

I thought it was ok to use YYYY-MM-DD in this context.  Do I need to use the full date time format?  Or am I bumping into some quirk of the developer console?

Comment: Is `Date__c` a Date only field or a DateTime field? For the latter you will want something like 
`SELECT Site__c FROM Session__c 
Where Date__c = 2012-11-6T00:00:00Z`. See [Date Formats and Date Literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

Comment: When I tried a datetime field with a date constant the message changed to "must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes". Without quotes is the way to go but as to why the "Unknown error parsing query" I don't know.

Comment: It's a Date only field.

Comment: Fyi a missing = or == in the date test gives and "Unknown error parsing query".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Site__c, Cluster__c, Date__c, Num_Att_records__c 
FROM Session__c  
Where Session__c.SiteProgram__r.Name = 'Brattleboro' AND Date__c = 2012-11-06
```

Note the leading `0` on the `06`.

The format is YYYY-MM-DD, so you need to pad the extra `0`.

Comment: Seems like an easy enough thing to miss. Took me a bit of trial and error to spot the missing 0.